# spring java avoid json serialization for specific url

Tags: java, json, image, spring, jackson

I am adding some support to a web application.
This application has the following configuration:

```
<bean class="mx.org.rfe.ife.siirfe.comun.web.spring.bindings.CustomBindingInitializer"
      id="customWebBindingInitializer" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer" ref="customWebBindingInitializer" />
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list id="beanList">
            <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" >
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
```

There are some @ResuestMapping controller methods on a separate product that return a ResponseEntity with an image on it, and corresponding jsp that loads them.
The response entity has its header with content-type set to MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG

However, the client browser is getting the image in Base64 format and not displaying at all because the page expects a clean image.

It is jacksont who is making the serialization. 
Is there a simple way to avoid that behaviour for those specific controller methods (urls) without changing much of the code? as others parts of the code rely on jackson, I would like to avoid breaking other parts of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see content negotiation configuration in the snippet you provided, do you have one? Read up on it on the spring.io blog [here](http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc/).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. It helped a lot. I had to modify the code quite a bit, most @ RequestMapping annotations lacked a value and it was complaining about ambiguity. That error only came out after I updated Spring dependencies version to 3.2.4 (it was 3.1 originally). I added the parameter "produces" to the @ RequestMapping to signal that they produce an image. I thought that the headers having Content-type set to image/jpg was enough, but it wasn't.